# CP2102 device is not listed in /dev on macOS 10.13

Tags: macos, hardware, driver

I have the ESP32 board with Silicon Labs CP2102 controller. When I connect it to my MacBook, I can get the details about this device using the command `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`, but it is not listed in `/dev` as a virtual serial port - so I can't communicate with it.

```
    CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller:

      Product ID: 0xea60
      Vendor ID: 0x10c4  (Silicon Laboratories, Inc.)
      Version: 1.00
      Serial Number: 0001
      Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
      Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
      Location ID: 0x14200000 / 5
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 100
      Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

I'm using the official driver downloaded from https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers.

Any ideas how to make it visible in `/dev`? I have also Windows installed on the same computer where it works fine, so the HW and the USB cable are OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that macOS High Sierra has blocked all unsigned / unmanaged kernel extensions and the SiLabs kernel extension guide doesn’t have information on how to manually enable the required extensions.

An excellent overview of this process is at man blogs - here is one such guide:

- https://grahamgilbert.com/blog/2017/09/11/enabling-kernel-extensions-in-high-sierra/

Here are steps to allow this extension specifically:

1. Go to "System Preferences" -> "Security & Privacy"
2. In the bottom of the window, you will see a message "System software from developer "SiLabs" was blocked from loading."
3. Click on "Allow" button
4. Restart your Mac

Now my device is listed as `/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART` and everything work as expected.

Comment: Great question and even better answer. Thanks for letting people know about the extra steps. I’ve added a blog I hope you don’t mind my option of it being “excellent” added. Please edit the post as needed to suit your needs if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your board is recognised as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu) link, and if yes and still no communications, you may need to install libusb with homebrew or similar. A good tool to play with before anything else is CoolTerm (easy to find...).